# how to make flex item take the whole width of the container so other items will come below?

Tags: css, flexbox

this is the result: [image]

just basic display flex, but what i want to achieve here is put the 2 items below it, so the first item occupy the upper container and will be centered using margin auto? I am thinking of using flex column but i think it's not right

Comment: give `width: 100%` to each item and `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: @AkashPinnaka i don't want their widths change, hmm

Comment: Why you are not preferring `flex-direction: column;`?

Comment: add different container for one you need above and other two in another container. it does it

Comment: so it cannot be done with just one flex container?

Comment: have a flex container with `flex-direction:row` inside it have another `flex-direction:column`

Comment: Why not use grid in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:
Width: calc(50% - 2px) is used to negate the 2 px of borders used;

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
background-color:pink;
}
.box{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color: cyan;
border: 1px black solid;
}
.box1{
width:calc(50% - 2px);
height:100px;
background-color: green;
border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```